# How to find an upperbound on the time of depopulation of an urban enviroment

Tags: statistics, reference-request

Given an urban area such as a shopping mall, is there a statistical model that estimates how often during a working day the area becomes depopulated and what is the maximum time of depopulation?

By depopulation I mean that the number of people per unit area becomes zero.

In particular I am interested to know the answer to this question: **Can we say that typical urban areas are usually populated (during the working day) and there is an upper-bound for the depopulation time?** any article that exposes some research regarding this subject would be useful.

Comment: Are you including the people who work there?   Unless there's some catastrophic event that requires the place to  be evacuated, there will always be people there during working hours.

Comment: @Robert Israel Yes, I agree. But there is also the question of density. The shopping mall is never depopulated but the number of people can be so low that the majority surface of the mall is depopulated. Maybe I should reformulate the question.

Comment: Yes, you should.